# How would humans evolve in this star system?

Tags: evolution, environment, gravity

Say that a large amount of humans settled in this system and have been living there for a few tens of thousands of years. The system is a binary system with two stars, a sun-like yellow dwarf and a red dwarf. There are two inhabited planets. One is mostly covered in ice, just barely warm enough for habitation and has 10% less gravity than earth, the other is perfect for human comfortability, but has 30% more gravity than earth and has three moons, all of which are heavier than our moon. It's surface is also about 90% covered in ocean. The atmosphere is about 1.2 Atms of pressure on both planets, with very similar composition to earth's. How would the human settlers evolve on these two planets over tens of thousands of years?

Comment: How many tens of thousands of years?

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE Probably 70-90,000 years. If more is required in order to generate significant changes, then I can go higher than 100,000.

Comment: bigger bum for insulation as well as to circumvent slipped disc

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I gave +1 to @D'Monlord's answer. Evolution occurs over millions of years, not tens of thousands. You might... *maybe...* see a small lessening of height and increase in lower body muscle mass... *maybe.* There are a bazillion variables when it comes to evolution and you've only told us 3-5 per planet. Worse, there's a very wide variety of physiology in humanity, and everything you've told us could fit within existing physiology.

Comment: Which reminds me, for future reference, please be aware that asking more than one question per post is literally a reason to close the post (click on "close" and read "Needs More Focus.") Asking what happens on two different planets is asking two questions. Asking about "the star system" doesn't make it one question.

Answer (score 4):

They would not. Not in any significant manner.

Homo Sapiens is mostly unchanged over last 10k years. We almost completely excluded natural selection. The better our technology is the lest natural selection is a factor in survival. It doesn't look like we got significantly more capable or smart - we just learned to use tools and change the world around us.

One of the main evolutionary mechanisms is excluded from our life. People with genetic problems who would be guaranteed to die in childhood 100 years now live to 80 years.

There is one relatively recent mutation, ability to consume milk. Lactose tolerance emerged ~4300 years ago in Europe. It improved kid's chances of survival because humans didn't have advanced agriculture which now mostly exclude malnutrition as a factor for baby survival.

This mutation wouldn't emerge now. We have less and less reasons to adapt to out environment. It is very likely that we start intentionally changing our genome soon. Evolution is mostly non-factor for humans.

Also, it looks like you want someone to write the story.

Comment: OP says they're willing to do up to 100,000 years, however. I think that changes the equation.

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE - how? Anatomically modern humans emerged ~300 000 years ago. And these are colonist, they have technology way beyond anything we can dream of. They are presumably part of greater humanity in space which means evolution of any locally isolated traits is almost impossible.

Comment: @D'Monlord Yep, unless OP is dumping the original colonists there with little to none of even the most basic tech or equipment (and definitely no science or tech manuals) and they then remain isolated it's not happening, you'd have to isolate them and deny them modern tech if you really wanted results.